# How to validate field conditionally using Struts 2 Validation?

Tags: validation, jsp, struts2, annotations, conditional-statements

I am a newbie on Struts2 and sorry for my poor English as it is not my mother language.

Assume the form has 1 multiple select box and 3 text fields:

**Multiple Select box:**
Name: `sb01`, Options: `[value, label]`: `[1, Type1], [2, Type2], [3, Type3]`

```
<s:select name="sb01" multiple="multiple" list="#{1:'Type1', 2:'Type2',3:'Type3'}"></s:select>
```

**3 text fields:** (`TextField1`, `TextField2`, `TextField3`)

```
<s:textfield name="TextField1" />
<s:textfield name="TextField2" />
<s:textfield name="TextField3" />
```

If Type1 is selected, user needs to input TextField1.

If `Type2` is selected, user needs to input `TextField2`.

If Type3 is selected, user needs to input TextField3.

If Type1,2,3 are selected, user needs to input all the textfields.
so on and so forth.

**How can the textfields be validated conditionally?**
I would like to do it by using xml or annotation instead of writing validate() method in action class because the code will be too long for reading and maintaining when fields grow.

I have done something like below but the logic is incorrect as it still requires all three options to be selected.

```
@FieldExpressionValidator(expression = "sb01.contain(1)", message="")
@RequiredStringValidator(message = "please fill in Textfield1.")
public String getTextField1(){ return TextField1; }

@FieldExpressionValidator(expression = "sb01.contain(2)", message="")
@RequiredStringValidator(message = "please fill in Textfield2.")
public String getTextField2(){ return TextField2; }

@FieldExpressionValidator(expression = "sb01.contain(3)", message="")
@RequiredStringValidator(message = "please fill in Textfield3.")
public String getTextField3(){ return TextField3; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use field validators, because the field validator is applied on the field annotated with it. And if you have three field validators all of them are applied on each field during validation process. Instead you can use one non-field validator that validated all three fields simultaneously. Setting dynamically a field which is required doesn't tell struts or adjust it to reconfigure validators. None of them actually should be marked as required because you can remove the mark of each one.